# Wordpress is resizing my image automatically—how to turn this off?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I keep running up against poor quality in my uploaded images on this site: http://www.rfm-inc.com.

Particularly with the slider image on the home page.

When I inspected, I noticed some HTML that says.

```html
<img src="http://rfm-inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Windmill2-1140x713.jpg" alt="windmill2" width="1140" title="Our machines. Our team. Your big ideas." class="woo-image slide-image" draggable="false">
```

Wordpress seems to be drawing on a different image than the original (which is at "http://rfm-inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Windmill2.jpg".

When I change the inspector text to this, it works fine.

I'd like to turn this feature off completely, and rely only on my Photoshop and CSS skills to get the desired result.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just chose the size of image to use when selecting it via Wordpress' Media Manager. You should be able to select *Full* (rather than *Large* or similar).

Comment: I can't. I'm using a featured image and featured images don't have that function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an image WP automatically saves the original file plus it also creates a series of thumbnails in different sizes. These smaller images will then be uses on your theme templates when needed in order to load the optimum size image every time and improve the load speed of your site.

By default, WordPress saves the “full” size, “large”, “medium” and “thumbnail”, and you can control the px size of these from Settings -> Media.

Now that being said the reason why you are seeing some images pixelated is because your theme is loading a WP generated thumbnail that is a size too small. In order to change that you’ll need to modify your code slightly in order to tell WordPress which image size to load. You can read more about WP functions to retrieve images in different generated sizes here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image

Comment: I tried to figure out what that page was about, but I really have no idea. This is featured image, so I'm assuming there's something about featured images in the theme that is limiting the size

Comment: Oops. Accidentally posted that last comment.

Comment: Did it again. So... I was saying. Not sure how to adjust the featured image or even where to begin.

Comment: Go to Settings -https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/ Media. Change the px size of your Thumbnail image there and then use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails to regenerate your images, otherwise the new size will only apply to the images you upload from now on but not to the ones already uploaded.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried this, but nothing changed that I can see. Also, my problem isn't with ALL Thumbnails (and I'm reluctant to tweak anything that's not broken). My problem is with the featured image in the slide on the first page. Wordpress is using http://rfm-inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Windmill2-1140x713.jpg as the source, but I want this: http://rfm-inc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Windmill2.jpg. Hmm.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunatelly you'll need to change some code to fix that. Your slide is loading the "large" size of the image (by default is 1024px wide) when you want it to load the "full" size image. That can only be changed through code that I know of. Probably you have something like this somewere in your slider code `wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, "large" );` and you want it to be `wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, "full" );`

Comment: Right that's what I thought. That should be workable. Will check back in a bit.

Comment: Another question. Where would I find the slider code? Any suggestions for finding it? It's not like CSS where I can easily find the line/file.

Comment: It is not CSS, that is in your PHP code. Unfortunately were that line of code is depends on how your slider is generated. If the slider is generated by your theme then it will be somewere in your theme's files, on the other hand if it's generated by a plugin then you should look for it in your plugin's files. Each theme/plugin has a different structure, so it's really hard to say

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Basically, there's a file in my theme (theme "Resort" by WooThemes) called "featured-slider.php". There was a line of code in there that was set like this:

```html
$image = woo_image( 'width=1440&noheight=true&class=slide-image&link=img&return=true' );
```

and I changed it to this:

```html
$image = woo_image( 'width=2160&noheight=true&class=slide-image&link=img&return=true' );
```

Now I need to figure out how to crop that image to a different height with CSS, but at least that part's over.

Thanks Guillermo et al.